# SCM: How can trunk have the latest code since inception of the project?

Tags: svn, version-control

I am trying to understand SCM in tool agnostic way, and I have some doubts over the thing that "TRUNK should have the latest code and should have all the newest feature".

For example, let us consider JDK project, and would it mean that when this project started it would have a "TRUNK" and that trunk has undergoes all the addition , deletion while going from JDK 1 to JDK 8 ?  I am having difficulty as to how a TRUNK of a project can have all the changes spanning years.

I did refer to various questions in SO, but I am not still clear on how can a TRUNK have latest source codes since inception of a project.

Any help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Considering same SVN repo is used throughout the project since the inception.

Trunk is a default branch in SVN, just like "master" in Git. Once development starts, branches are forked out from Trunk as per need. Now over the span of years, these branches gets merged with each other, including Trunk.

Its not necessary that each and every feature/a bug fix is developed and checked into Trunk. It can be the case that the code is checked into any of the available branch and the same gets merged into Trunk.

> I did refer to various questions in SO, but I am not still clear on how can a TRUNK have latest source codes since inception of a project.

*Latest source code on Trunk?* It depends on SCM design. Trunk can have all the latest code, it may not build or not in deploy-able/production-ready state. Some like to have all the latest code on some branch and keep Trunk with stable/production-ready state.

*since inception of a project?* Yes, since merges happen with commit history maintained, all the branches including Trunk will have all the code available till latest commit on that branch.